# How to match 2 patterns within a single line

Tags: perl

I have the following Java code

```
fun(GUIBundle.getString("Key1"), GUIBundle.getString("Key2"));
```

I use Perl to parse the source code, to see whether "Key1" and "Key2" is found within $gui_bundle.

```
while (my $line = <FILE>) {
    $line_number++;
    if ($line =~ /^#/) {
        next;
    }
    chomp $line;

    if ($line =~ /GUIBundle\.getString\("([^"]+)"\)/) {
        my $key = $1;
        if (not $gui_bundle{$key}) {
            print "WARNING : key '$key' not found ($name $line_number)\n";
        }
    }
}
```

However, for the way I write the code, I can only verify "Key1". How I can verify "Key2" as well?

Comment: You can use `$.` to get the line number; there is no need to keep track of it on your own.  (http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the `g` modifier and put it into a `while` loop:

```
while ($line =~ /GUIBundle\.getString\("([^"]+)"\)/g) { ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `/g` modifier to the regular expression match, in list context:

```
@matches = $line =~ /GUIBundle\.getString\("([^"]+)"\)/g;
```

Given your example line, `@matches` will contain strings: `'Key1'` and `'Key2'`.

Answer (score 0):

Exchange the `if` construct with a `while`, and using the global-matching modifier, `/g`:

```
while (my $line = <FILE>) {

    $line_number++;

    next if $line =~ /^#/;
    chomp $line;

    while ($line =~ /GUIBundle\.getString\("([^"]+)"\)/g) { #"

        my $key = $1;
        warn "key '$key' not found ($name $line_number)" unless $gui_bundle{$key};
    }
}
```